# refresh javascript file when run asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have `myfile.js` file in my webpage

and when it runs it goes this link

```
localhost:44301/rep
```

when I change the script myfile.js

the changes does not reflect in the webpage when it runs again

I rebuilt the my web app

cleaned it

yet same old file and my changes are not in the myfile.js

is there anyway to force .js file to refresh?

if not can I change the number in the `localhost:XXXXX/rep` ?

Comment: This is too broad without more information. I suspect you are serving from a folder like `wwwroot` and also that your build target has no idea about your JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found tha answer

I added version number to the js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfil.js?version=2"></script>
```